# How do I move the Windows 10 Start Menu apps list to the left edge?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, desktop-customization

I've seen the apps list *permanently expanded* at the very left edge of the Windows 10 Start Menu, rather than hidden or in a separate column.  How is this done, please?  I like the idea and it's driving me crazy not finding the setting!

Perhaps it was just a particular update to the OS?  I am in corporate I.T., so random add-ons or installations are unlikely to be the explanation.  I've only seen it on one or two PCs out of hundreds I deal with.

[image: Windows 10 Start Menu]

Thanks, Mark

Comment: The only setting I found that is in any way related is Customization → Start → Show app list in Start menu. But disabling it doesn’t really result in what you’re seeing.

Comment: "How is this done, please?" - What version of Windows 10 are you running?  What version of Windows 10 is that screenshot from exactly?  Is that screenshot the way you want the start menu to behave?

Comment: @Ramhound This screenshot is from the Internet.  I need to relocate one of the laptops where I saw the menu like this for myself.  There are quite a few similar screenshots to be found, but I have been unable to find an explanation.  Personally and at work, we run Win 10 Pro in various states up to 1909.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the current build (1909) and on the next build (2004) you can expand the left most column, but not natively delete it. So the alphabetic menu remains where it is

Comment: Thanks.  I will have to find time to explore the versions.  I've actually been in the process of ensuring updates are all present when I've noticed this menu configuration, but didn't pay too much attention because I figured it was an easily discoverable option!

Comment: The newer versions allow expanding the menu which goes the other way from what you want